# Replace character but provide proper escaping

Tags: c#, regex, algorithm

I want to replace a `&` character with a `§` character but provide a proper way to escape the & sign. I want to use the character `\` for escaping but also to escape itself.

So basically:

Input:

```
&1 \&2 \\&3 \\\&4 \\
```

Output:

```
§1 &2 \§3 \&4 \
```

It seems like Regex is the proper way to do this but I can't get it working.
This is how far my Regex is for the & signs:

```
(?<=(?<!\\)(?:(?:\\){2})*)&(?=.)
```

I want to use this for C#, if this should be important.

EDIT: I have changed the Regex, now I just need to take care of the backslashes.
EDIT 2: Thanks for giving me serious feedback instead of just downvoting without Reasons /s

Comment: Well, I am still wondering why the required output is like that. Shouldn't it be ``§1 \&2 \\§3 \\\&4 \\``

Comment: @RuiJarimba \& has one backslash for escaping the & and should not be replaced with §, but \\&3 has two backslashes, so the backslashes will escape itself and show \§3. It is like how you would escape the quote in most languages (`\"` would be `"` in a string, `\\"` would be a backslash and the end of the string.). I hope that you understand what I meant now.

Comment: So, you want to replace `&` and then "shrink" double backslashes? `var res = Regex.Replace(text, @"(?<=(?<!\\)(?:\\{2})*)&", "§").Replace("\\\\", "\\")`?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Because I want to use the \ for escaping, so \\ would become a single \ , \& would become & and & should become §. It is like a string in C# (or most other languages) "\" \\\"\\" would become `" \"\`

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Not exactly, your code would give the output `§1 \&2 \§3 \\&4 \`

Comment: I still think it will be easier to do with 2 regexps: `Regex.Replace(Regex.Replace(text, @"(?<=(?<!\\)(?:\\{2})*)&", "§"), @"(?:(\\){2})+(?(?=\\&)\\|)", "$1")`. Note I am not sure about how backslashes must be handled. Probably, `Replace(..., @"(?:(\\){2})+\\?", "$1")` as the second step is enough.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Wrong Output:
    `§1 \&2 \§3 \&4 \` EDIT: Did't see your Note

Answer (score 3):

Is it really necessary to use Regex?

You could use following code snippet:

```
var output = new StringBuilder();
bool escape = false;
for (var i = 0; i < input.Length; ++i)
{
    if (escape)
    {
        output.Append(input[i]);
        escape = false;
    }
    else
    {
        switch (input[i])
        {
            case '\\':
                escape = true;
                break;
            case '&':
                output.Append('§');
                break;
            default:
                output.Append(input[i]);
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

`input` is a string with escape symbols, e.g. `&1 \&2 \\&3 \\\&4 \\`

`output.ToString()` will contain the correct string.

Comment: I like this, but IMO this seems like a hacky way of implementing this, what would be if I don't want to escape & but want to escape two characters like &= ? But thank you and you got an upvote ;D

Comment: Regarding two chars, you could extent `switch` with more `case` or you could organize your re-mapping rules in dictionary. Also, this way is less CPU intensive then Regex specially on big texts :)

Comment: and is it possible to determine the length while initializing the StringBuilder?

Comment: You may set it as input.Length, it will guarantee no redundant memory allocations during the processing.

Comment: But the output will be shorter, so this is what I call hacky (I know, its minimal, but still)

Answer (score 2):

Here is a pure regex solution. Strategy is to first escape any & character which is preceded by zero or even number of slashes to half the number of slashes and § character. Then next escape \& to & and then escape any \\ to \

```
public class Program
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string str = @"&1\&2ttt\\&3    \\\&4 \\  ";
        Console.WriteLine("Input:  " + str);
        str = Regex.Replace(str, @"([^&\\]+|^)((\\)\\)*&", "$1$2§");
        str = Regex.Replace(str, @"\\&", "&");
        str = Regex.Replace(str, @"\\\\", "\\");
        Console.WriteLine("Output: " + str);
    }
}
```

This gives following output as expected in your post,

```
Input:  &1\&2ttt\\&3    \\\&4 \\  
Output: §1&2ttt\§3    \&4 \
```

Comment: Output should be §1 &2 \§3 \&4 \  not everything §

Comment: Oh sorry, I overlooked your output and thought all were same. Apologies for that. I have updated my answer to give you the expected output and updated the strategy too.

Comment: That's nice, but it doesn't work if you would remove the spaces of the input (These could be not there or there could be anything instead of the spaces even more characters)

Comment: Although my program worked for any variable number of spaces in between tokens but I have updated it to work with no spaces or multiple spaces or even any other characters in between to make it work as you wanted.

Answer (score 0):

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace ConsoleApp20
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string str = @"&1 \&2 \\&3 \\\&4 \\  ";
            var s = str.Split(' ');
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            foreach (var item in s)
            {
                var f = item.Split('\\');

                if (f.Length % 2 == 0)
                {
                    if (f.Length > 3)
                    {
                        sb.Append($@"\{f[f.Length - 1]}");
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        sb.Append(f[f.Length - 1]);
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    if (f.Length > 2)
                    {
                        sb.Append($@"\{f[f.Length - 1].Replace('&', '§')}");
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        sb.Append(f[f.Length - 1].Replace('&', '§'));
                    }
                }
                sb.Append("  ");
            }
            Console.WriteLine(sb.ToString());
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Doesn't work if I remove a space (should be possible too)